# Getting publish fail in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, publish

I just trying to publish my website developed in asp.net MVC, which is built get succeed. but while publishing, I am getting this failure status at the end :

Publishing folder bin/es/.svn/tmp/prop-base...
Publishing folder bin/es/.svn/tmp/props...
Publishing folder bin/es/.svn/tmp/text-base...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Before these lines I am getting :

```
Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_allcaps.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_allcaps.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_bold.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_bold.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_columns.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_columns.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_complete.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_complete.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_direction.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_direction.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_double_underline.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_double_underline.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_dropcaps.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_dropcaps.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_fit.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_fit.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_flip.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_flip.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_font_default.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_font_default.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_heading_1.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_heading_1.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_heading_2.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_heading_2.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_heading_3.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_heading_3.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_heading_4.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_heading_4.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_heading_5.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_heading_5.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_heading_6.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_heading_6.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_horizontalrule.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_horizontalrule.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_indent.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_indent.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_indent_remove.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_indent_remove.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_inverse.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_inverse.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_italic.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_italic.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_kerning.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_kerning.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_left_to_right.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_left_to_right.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_letter_omega.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_letter_omega.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_letterspacing.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_letterspacing.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_linespacing.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_linespacing.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_list_bullets.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_list_bullets.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_list_numbers.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_list_numbers.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_lowercase.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_lowercase.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_lowercase_a.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_lowercase_a.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_mirror.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_mirror.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_padding_bottom.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_padding_bottom.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_padding_left.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_padding_left.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to add 'Content/images/icons/silk/text_padding_right.png' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Content\images\icons\silk\text_padding_right.png'.  The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But these files are deleted. how to remove this ? I want to be clean built , published application. Can this failuar cause of failuar  in functionality in spplicstion , if i deploy this kind of website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because your files are referenced by your project but removed on disk. You have two options for removing your references:

Remove your files in Visual Studio (right click in solution explorer and `Delete`), this will remove all references to them.

Or

Remove them from your project file. To do this, open your `.csproj` and locate `<ItemGroup>`. From there, remove all `<Content Include="" />` that does not exist on disk.

Comment: Ok , but if i deploy this kind of solution , then will any impact on its internal functionality ,like file upload or something like this?

Comment: Notice folder names `bin/es/.svn/tmp/prop-base` etc. .svn folders are for version control and probably should not be published.

Comment: @Artem K. If they are from different version control let say then what will happen? I could not get your comment. please explain

Comment: Published .svn folders on the website gives access to the source code and in fact is a potential security vulnerability: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=838981